# Understanding the intution behind Lp spaces

Tags: real-analysis

I am studying Analysis on my own.

Back in college, I seem to recall in an engineering class the (non-technical) claim that $L^p$ spaces talk about the rate of convergence of "nice" indefinite integrals.  If I recall right,

$$\frac{1}{1+x^2} $$ would be in $L^2$, since

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{1+x^2}=k_1 $$ for some $k_1$, and

$$\frac{1}{1+x^3} $$ would be in $L^3$, since

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{1+x^3}=k_2 $$ for some $k_2$, etc.

This was, of course, explained using Riemann integrals at the time.

But is this the right intuition for nicely behaved functions, or was I led astray and need to rethink it all from scratch as I read?

Comment: It might help to get a standard elementary calculus text and look back over the sections on convergence tests for improper integrals (the kind with infinite limits) and infinite series, and notice the fundamental role as "measuring sticks" (for comparison tests) that integrals of $x^p$ and the $p$-series have. Many of the basic manipulation tools and convergence understanding for the integral $L^p$ spaces and the sequence $l^p$ spaces can be obtained by a more "grown-up" review of that material.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is incorrect. A function $f$ belongs to the $L^p$ space if $|f|^p$ has a finite integral. Thus $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac 1{1+x^2} \, dx < \infty \implies \frac{1}{1+x^2} \in L^1,$$
whereas
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left( \frac 1{1+x^2} \right)^2 \, dx < \infty \implies \frac{1}{1+x^2} \in L^2.$$

Moreover, $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{1 + x^3} \, dx$ is divergent.

Comment: So it is a member of both $L^1$ and $L^2$, but not $L^k$ for $k>2$, correct?

Comment: I think it is not hard to see that $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{1+x^2} \right)^k \, dx < \infty$$ for all $k > \dfrac 12$.

Comment: To the proposer, We do not to restrict $L^p$ spaces to $p\in \Bbb Z^+.$ We can include any $p\geq 1. $